# Error while dumping data from oracle DB to excel - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.hssf.record.BOFRecord.setVersion(S)V

Tags: java, apache-poi, wildfly, xls, data-dump

I am getting this error while dumping the data from the DB to the excel.
POI jar is used to copy the data from DB to excel.
The code is being run in wildfly application server.
Following is the stacktrace

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/STD].[jsp]] (http--127.0.0.1-8888-1) Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.hssf.record.BOFRecord.setVersion(S)V     
at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.Workbook.createBOF(Workbook.java:801) [poi.jar:]   
at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.Workbook.createWorkbook(Workbook.java:255) [poi.jar:]  
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:142) [poi.jar:]  
at org.apache.jsp.Framewrk.DownExcelFile_jsp._jspService(DownExcelFile_jsp.java:823)    
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]    
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]     
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]    
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]   
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]    
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]   
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]   
at com.github.ziplet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter.doFilter(CompressingFilter.java:300) [ziplet-2.0.0.jar:]  
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]   
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]   
at iwebz.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:21) [classes:]   
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]   
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]   
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]     
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]     
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:397) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final-RECOMPILE.jar:7.1.1.Final]  
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]   
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]   
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:567) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]   
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]   
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]     
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]    
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]     
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved.
Different version of the same jar were present in the wildfly lib folder, hence the issue.
One jar was with the name **poi.jar** and and the same poi files were present in **org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.2.1.v20120918-1113.jar**